# Labeled while loops in Javascript

Tags: javascript, statements

My confusion stems from this example labelled statement:

```
myLoop : while (expression) {
    continue myLoop;
}
```

and the syntax of a general labelled statement:

```
identifier : statement
```

What exactly is being labelled in the example?

isn't the whole block of code:

```
while (expression) 
    statement
```

considered a single statement? Or is `while(expression)` itself a statement? Or is `while` a statement by itself?

Why isn't the entire:

```
while (expression) {
    continue myLoop;
}
```

labelled under `myLoop` and not just `while(expression)`. Or is that even happening?

Answer (score 5):

I'd never seen labelled while loops before, but according to this http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/looping-in-javascript/ it *is* the whole while loop that is being labelled.

The use for it is to break out of a particular loop, handy with loops-in-loops e.g. (example taken from the link)

```
myOuterLoop : while (condition) {
 myInnerLoop : while (condition) {
    if (whatever) {
        break myOuterLoop;
    }
    if (whatever2) {
        break; // Same as 'break myInnerLoop;'
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What's being labelled isn't a block of code, it's just a particular line.  So wherever your label *myLoop* is, writing *continue myLoop* is like saying "jump to that spot and continue execution".

But actually, in this example:

```
myLoop : while (expression) {
    continue myLoop;
}
```

The use of the [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) is completely redundant.  You would write it as follows and the effect would be identical:

```
while (expression) {
    continue;
}
```

That's because *[continue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue)* by default means, go to the beginning of the loop's next iteration.

Comment: Moreover, A loop (In this case `while`) is dealt like a single statement, even though it comprises of multiple statements in itself(Block of code).